# Форвардная декларация typedef

Tags: c++, c, typedef

Допустим, определен новый тип

```
typedef vector<int> int_vect;
```

Каким образом для данного типа int_vect можно сделать форвардную декларацию в другом заголовочном файле? Определяемый тип не является структурой или классом.

Comment: Это никоим образом не определение нового типа. И, откровенно говоря, непонятно, что вам нужно - не хотите показать пример кода?..

Comment: Зачем делать "форвардную" декларацию, когда можно сделать вот такую полную декларацию? О какой "форвардности" идет речь? Что означает ремарка "Определяемый тип не является структурой или классом."?

Comment: Есть заголовочный файл с описанием typedef, зачем дублировать это описание в других используемых заголовочных файлах, которых хотят использовать это описание? Хочу компилятору сказать, что int_vect определен.
Уточнение о структуре и классе указано для того, что форвардную декларацию для них можно сделать struct int_vect или class int_vect.
Пример с vector<int> упрощен, детали не сильно важны.

Comment: Совершенно незачем дублировать. Просто включите заголовочный файл с объявлением `int_vect` в тот файл, который должен его использовать.

Comment: Цель - минимизация зависимостей времени компиляции. Включение заголовочного файла с описанием int_vect в другие заголовочные файлы нежелательно.

Comment: *"Включение заголовочного файла с описанием int_vect в другие заголовочные файлы нежелательно"* В этом файле есть еще что-то громоздкое в дополнение к `typedef`ам? Если да, вынесите `typedef`ы в отдельный файл и включайте его. Если нет, тогда не понимаю, чем вам не нравится просто включать этот хедер.

Comment: А зачем минимизировать зависимости времени компиляции? Если вы планируете таким образом ускорить компиляцию, то это безнадежный подход.

Comment: [минимизация зависимостей времени компиляции] Минимизация зависимостей времени компиляции делается с помощью #ifndef в начале хедера. Если проект один, то проще работать с одним хедером. Если проектов несколько и у них есть общие типы, то сделайте хедер со всеми общими типами и включайте его в хедеры всех проектов.

Comment: @VTT, не соглашусь с вами. Изменение этого заголовочного файла вызовет перекомпиляцию всех модулей, использующих измененный заголовочный файл, чего не будет при использовании форвардной декларации.

Comment: Перекомпиляция всех единиц трансляции, использующих этот заголовочный файл не должна пугать при надлежащим образом организованной сборке. Вообще говоря, перекомпиляция заново - это наиболее часто выполняющийся вариант сборки. Поэтому как раз такой сценарий и имеет смысл оптимизировать. @pepsicoca1 `#ifndef` делается для защиты от множественного включения одного и того же заголовка в единицу трансляции. А "хедер со всеми общими типами" - это прямой путь к хрупкому проекту. Каждый файл должен включать все заголовочные файлы, которые ему требуются.

Comment: @VTT [прямой путь к хрупкому проекту] Что такое "хрупкий проект"?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Хрупкий - это противоположность гибкому. То бишь попытки доработки / рефакторинга / переиспользования этого кода будут затруднены. https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rs-contained